# Why potential energy of a non-relativistic particle in an expanding universe is $ma^2\phi$?

Tags: cosmology, potential-energy, neutrinos

I have been reading a paper on neutrino clustering in an expanding universe: [see section 3, particularly 3.3.2 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0461). In this paper for non-relativistic neutrinos, which travel through a potential well of Cold Dark Matter, the energy function is defined as follows,
$$E(\vec{x},\vec{q},\tau)=\frac{q^2}{2m}+ma^2(\tau)\phi(\vec{x},\tau).$$
Here, $\tau$ is conformal time, $q$ is the comoving momentum, $a(\tau)$ is the scale factor, and $\phi(\vec{x},\tau)$ is the potential well. I do not understand how the factor $a^2$ comes about with the potential energy. Kindly explain.

And also there is a derivation that claims that the rate of change of the above energy function is much less if the potential energy varies in the Hubble time scale. What is the mathematical statement/inequality that describes such a potential and also how to derive the above result?